# Country specific SEO

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I have a wordpress site which is located at a .com address. The site is a simple 4 page personal site with my academic credentials, publications and a health blog that I started.

I have done quite a bit of seo and I rank pretty high for the keywords i want on google.co.uk. However, I do not rank at all on google.com.mt which is the Malta specific search.

I have therefore just bought the .com.mt domain and pointed the DNS nameservers to my current host provider and redirected it to the .com address.

My goal is to make sure I don't screw up my google.co.uk search ranking, while starting to rank on google.com.mt

I'm I doing the right thing or do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it...

Answer (score 1):

I would implement Maltese versions of your pages and set the language in the `<html>` tag with the `lang` attribute. Then, I would set [hreflang meta tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) in your pages too to help search engines serve them properly.

With this, English pages will be served in the English speaking community and Maltese pages will be served in the Maltese speaking community. Your existing SEO efforts should be safe.

Comment: If your address is a Malta address and other contact info follows suit, then perhaps adding contact markup via schema.org will help. Your ccTLD will help Google to know where to present your site, but the markup may also help with this. Google uses load-balance techniques and performance testing to automatically place sites into various data centers and on ccTLD specific Google sites.

Comment: thanks for the advice! However, I am interested in english language searches on google.com.mt since the demographic i am targeting is english speaking people (majority of maltese speak english). my wordpress site is linked to .com site... would i need to host a multisite wordpress site?

Comment: I think considering the size of your website and your requirements, that would be overkill.